# Interpreting 95%CIs - why perform formal statistical tests or multiple comparisons?

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons

95% (or other %) confidence intervals indicate the range in which we expect the true mean to lie with 95% probability (= 'confidence') according to the Central Limit Theorem, given the precision of the estimated mean (i.e. standard error of a sample mean).

I wish to interpret some data presented in a journal article as means with standard errors (and n) that were not tested statistically. It occurred to me that if I calculate 95%CIs for each sample I could infer whether there is a real difference. But, **is this true**?

To explain further (skip this if you already get what I'm asking). Probability rules suggest that given the true mean of each group lies outside their respective CIs with 5% probability, there is a <5% probability that the mean of **BOTH** groups lies outside their CIs and within the 'space' between CIs of the two groups (let's consider them to be very close together to push the boundaries of this question)

**The logical question that arises is why do we bother testing the groups formally (e.g. t-test, ANOVA)?** There has to be a reason(s) but I don't know it.

An extension to this question: given the conservative nature of multiple comparison tests when there are many groups in the analysis e.g. ANOVA with 5 groups (and the lack of agreement about how to approach this!) **can we instead infer which groups differ from comparing overlap in CIs** once we establish at least one pair of group means significantly differ?

Thanks in advance,
Dean

Comment: Cumming, G., & Finch, S. (2005). Inference by Eye: Confidence Intervals and How to Read Pictures of Data. American Psychologist, 60(2), 170–180. doi:10.1037/0003-066X.60.2.170
You'll enjoy this.

Comment: Selective testing (i.e. multiple comparisons) and selective estimation are different things. You can absolutely *not* use CIs for multiple testing.
See details in: 
Benjamini, Y., and D. Yekutieli. 2005. “False Discovery Rate-Adjusted Multiple Confidence Intervals for Selected Parameters.” Journal of the American Statistical Association 100 (469): 71–81.

Comment: I tried to read your cited article but it is too dense for me to digest. Could you summarise the reasons why "you can absolutely not use CIs for multiple testing"?